# Processing an array of objects according to element nesting via Vanilla JS / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that I have to process and then include data from it to HTML. The problem is that now everything is displayed one by one and if I try to toggle class to li element, it toggles to all li elements. The data can be changed dynamically so I cannot access elements by ID.

I want to access the "main" category first (desserts, water, tea), then be able to proceed to subcategory of the selected main category etc. Further I will create a menu like in the [screenshot (a one menu, a pic shows different states of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odGPm.jpg)

I have 2 problems now:

1. For some reason the main category isn't showing at all - why is it happening?
2. How can I access the elements according to hierarchy and nesting?

```js
const menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Desserts",
    groups: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Cold",
        groups: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Ice Cream",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Cold brew coffee",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Hot",
        groups: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: "Pancakes",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: "Apple pie",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Water",
    groups: []
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Tea",
    groups: [
      {
        id: 8,
        name: "Green tea",
        groups: [
          {
            id: 9,
            name: "With Jasmine",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            name: "Plain",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Black Tea",
        groups: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

let menuEl = document.querySelector(".funding__categories");

addElements(menuEl, menu[0].groups);

function addElements(parent, arr) {
  let allCategories = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
  allCategories.classList.add("parent");
  arr.forEach((el) => {
    let subCategory = allCategories.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    subCategory.dataset.id = el.id;
    subCategory.textContent = el.name;
    if (el.groups.length > 0) addElements(subCategory, el.groups);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="funding__categories"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is because you're passing `menu[0].groups` to the function. That skips over the top-level categories and starts at the items nested under `Desserts`. Pass `menu` as the argument.

I don't understand the second question. Access them in what way?

```js
const menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Desserts",
    groups: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Cold",
        groups: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Ice Cream",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Cold brew coffee",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Hot",
        groups: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: "Pancakes",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: "Apple pie",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Water",
    groups: []
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Tea",
    groups: [
      {
        id: 8,
        name: "Green tea",
        groups: [
          {
            id: 9,
            name: "With Jasmine",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            name: "Plain",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Black Tea",
        groups: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

let menuEl = document.querySelector(".funding__categories");

addElements(menuEl, menu);

function addElements(parent, arr) {
  let allCategories = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
  allCategories.classList.add("parent");
  arr.forEach((el) => {
    let subCategory = allCategories.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    subCategory.dataset.id = el.id;
    subCategory.textContent = el.name;
    if (el.groups.length > 0) addElements(subCategory, el.groups);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="funding__categories"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now it is clear for me. Regarding the second question: I wanted to toggle class like "main-category" to Desserts, Water and Tea, then a class "subcategory" to Cold, Hot, Black Tea and Green Tea and the class "item" to the rest. I think it will help me to create a menu shown in the screenshot